# How to test if function passed as parameter was called in Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jestjs, mocking

I have a function that receives another function as an argument. I would like to make sure it was called properly.

Function to be tested:

```
const loadNamespaces = (setNamespaces) => {
  namespaceAPI.getNamespaces().then(namespaces => {
    setNamespaces(namespaces);
  });
}
```

My main goal here was to assert `mockSetNamespaces` was called.

I was able to mock and assert `namespaceAPI.getNamespaces` was called by using `jest.spyOn` method, but that didn't work for asserting if `mockSetNamespaces` was called:

```
test("loadNamespaces", () => {
  const mockSetNamespaces = jest.fn();

  const mockNamespaces = [
    { endpoint: "mock namespace 1", rooms: [] },
  ];

  jest.spyOn(namespaceAPI, "getNamespaces").mockImplementation(() => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      resolve(mockNamespaces);
    });
  });

  SocketIOActions.loadNamespaces(mockSetNamespaces);

  expect(namespaceAPI.getNamespaces).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(mockSetNamespaces).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Error message received from Jest:

```
  ● loadNamespaces

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0
```

I've also tried to add `setNamespaces` to an object, so `jest.spyOn` method could be used, but also didn't assert method was called:

```
test("loadNamespaces", () => {
  const mockObject = {
    mockSetNamespaces: jest.fn(),
  };

  const mockNamespaces = [
    { endpoint: "mock namespace 1", rooms: [] },
  ];

  jest.spyOn(namespaceAPI, "getNamespaces").mockImplementation(() => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      resolve(mockNamespaces);
    });
  });

  jest.spyOn(mockObject, "mockSetNamespaces").mockImplementation(() => {
    console.log("Hello from spy function");
  });

  SocketIOActions.loadNamespaces(mockObject.mockSetNamespaces);

  expect(namespaceAPI.getNamespaces).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(mockObject.mockSetNamespaces).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Proof that mock function was actually called:

```
    console.log
      Hello from spy function
```

Is this the expected behavior from Jest? I would be glad to know if there is a cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Using `spyOn` when you need to mock specific function from the module instead of mocking all.

I would do in this way.

```js
// this will help you auto mock all namespaceAPI function. If you just need to mock "getNamespaces" then you stick with spyOn
jest.mock('namespaceAPI')

test("loadNamespaces", () => {
  // you can directly mock implementation in jest function, dont need to spy it again.
  const mockSetNamespaces = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    console.log("Hello from spy function");
  });

  SocketIOActions.loadNamespaces(mockSetNamespaces);

  expect(namespaceAPI.getNamespaces).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(mockSetNamespaces).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```